# How to add PDF files path to SQL database and access them ? ( C# )

Tags: c#, sql

I have to build a software which can search and display PDF files from a folder on the local network.
My supervisor was requesting to have a database and store the path of PDF files there(not to the PDF itself because of the large amount), so I can search and open them from the software.

I would greatly appreciate if you could give me some ideas for solving it.

Comment: Well how familiar are you with the whole database idea? This seems like a very easy task if you know where to begin. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. I was working with SQL databases during my classes, but I'm not sure where to begin this task.

Comment: What difficulty are you hitting? Storing a path is pretty simple - a `nvarchar(400)` ought to do it, even for UNC paths (`\\someserver\share\foo\bar\blap.pdf`). Personally, I would just store the *relative path* to some root stored elsewhere, i.e. if the root was `\\someserver\share\foo`, the relative path is `bar\blap.pdf` - makes it easy to move the entire document store just by reconfiguring the root, rather than updating every row. But back to my main point: what problem are you encountering?

Comment: I have about 1250 PDF files with various size in a specific folder on the local network that has to be somehow entered or added to a database(would be better if it's path) and from my software I have to search and open them. I'm not sure how to begin and work out a solution for this task. (It is my very first software outside university.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private string[,] GetImagesFromServerFolder()
    {
        IntPtr token;
        if (
            !NativeMethods.LogonUser([Server_Login_Name], [Server_Location],
                                     [Server_Login_Password], NativeMethods.LogonType.NewCredentials,
                                     NativeMethods.LogonProvider.Default, out token))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        try
        {
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate;

            if (!NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(
                token,
                NativeMethods.SecurityImpersonationLevel.Impersonation,
                out tokenDuplicate))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            try
            {
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext =
                    new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate).Impersonate())
                {
                    /******************* CODE FROM HERE *******************/

                    List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(_PHYSICAL SERVER LOCATION_));


                    return files;

                    /******************* CODE TO HERE *******************/
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if (!NativeMethods.CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate))
                    {
                        // Uncomment if you need to know this case.
                        ////throw new Win32Exception();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (!NativeMethods.CloseHandle(token))
                {
                    // Uncomment if you need to know this case.
                    ////throw new Win32Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**This will then return a list of all the .pdf files and locations**
You can then sore that in a DB.

Then, run through all the files in the list (In your main running method);

```
List<string> file = GetImagesFromServerFolder();  
foreach (var s in file)  
{  
        const string connStr = "INSERT INTO tblPdfLocations (location) VALUES (@location)";
        //Store the connection details as a string
    string connstr =
        String.Format(@"SERVER=[LOCATION]; UID=[USERNAME]; pwd=[PASSWORD]; Database=[DATABASE]");

    //Initialise the connection to the server using the connection string.
    _sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

        var sqlComm = new SqlCommand(connStr, _sqlConn) {CommandType = CommandType.Text};
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = s;

        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking doing this way. Only problem that I have 1250 PDF file, entering one by one manually the locations would take forever.

Comment: I have added actual code for you to use. This will iterate through all the files, and return the list. Remember: Only add code between the **Code Here** Tags. This is because the rest sorts out the transition between your currentPC and the Network PC

Comment: This will return a list of all files. How I actually add the list to Database?

Comment: Added the method. I made the insertion one-by-one because if something goes wrong with the bulk import, it would throw the entire process off. At least, with this, you can continue where you stopped.

Comment: Anytime. Hope you get it working! Don't hesitate to ask for anything else. Mark the post as accepted if you feel its resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you already solved it? You could have an application such as a service or even a command line application that could poll/manually look into a specified folder, from there you would get the full file location and persist this into your database.  When you need to search for the PDF you could perform a query against your database for PDF's that match your criteria.

You could even strip the filename from the filepath and query on that rather than the filepath and store the filepath in a different column (providing you're using a relational database).

**Edit**

Based on your comment on the other answer, I would stick with SQL server.  From what I understand you want to automatically "catologue" the PDFs dropped in that folder, you can do this by writing a simple [windows service](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp).  From that Windows service you can use an ORM (like Entity Framework) or ADO.net to persist your changes to your database.  From the application you wish to display the result (be it Web app or a Win forms application, whatever), you can just query the correct column in your DB

Resources:

[Entity Framework](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=entity%20framework%20tutorial&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb386876.aspx&ei=1AkqULiNLovgtQbvsICAAw&usg=AFQjCNGHLeUe7NP3kCC_HraFqnEpeBBo2A)

[Linq to Entities](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=querying%20in%20linq%20entity%20framework%20c%23&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb386964.aspx&ei=_gkqUOrmAdHGtAbl7oGwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEluu1qy2AKy7mfHcDpqHUJgNq8hw)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but this is one of my very first software and I'm not sure how I could implement your idea.

Comment: If you want some more help I can assist you if you wish, at least guide you to the right solution

Answer (score 0):

read about some ORM to work with database. For example, Entity Framework.

Comment: As he said, its his first assignment outside of college.  
Would be nice if you added some links, or a proper tutorial on what to do, instead of 2 very short sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a different perspective than the other answers provided because - the storage and retrieval of such documents like PDF, Word, JPEG etc files is well into the realms of "Content Management" (CM) applications. Although relatively new in the big world of IT - these applications are mature and offer industrial strength solutions.
They use database back-ends and offer a host of facilities - the one you are interested in is the usage of CM purely as a content repository.
You don't have to look at the offerings from the big vendors (ie. Oracle Webcenter) - there are free and well supported alternatives such as Drupal and Joomla. Each of them have API's which I assume will allow you to connect into their repositories from third-party applications.

You should be looking at a solution which can grow with your company's requirements and not look to reinvent something which is already out there.